# normalizing/merging nextauth.js provider and credentials session data (nextjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I am building a project that uses nextauth version 4.19 with 'credentials' (db) and Google as provider.

Everything works with the 'credentials' provider and I am able to get a session.user with all my db fields.

However, when I register/sign in using Google, the returned session only includes the data from google plus the token info.

I need to to be able to merge the data returned by google with my User fields and pass that to my client in the session object.

Here's my relevant code:

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { username, password } = credentials;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: username }).exec();

        const isValid = await user.comparePassword(password);

        if (!isValid) {
          return false;
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    signIn: async ({ user, account, profile }) => {
      console.log("signIn", user, account, profile);
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
          email: user.email,
        }).exec();

        if (existingUser) {
          console.log(
            "Google user already exists, returning existing user",
            existingUser
          );
          return existingUser;
        }

        console.log("New google account, saving in db...");
        const newUser = await User.create({
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: "googlepassword", // @TOOD: bcrypt this
          photo: user.image,
          provider: true,
          providerName: "google",
        });

        console.log("Google user saved, returning:", newUser);
        return newUser;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      user && (token.user = user);
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
    error: "/auth/signin", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
    newUser: "/auth/new-user", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

When I sign up with 'credentials', my session.user looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "640f9ecde855917558d80449",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$Skj418vLiKyc0yM/Wg3mJu9c5ahjn175zALf/XxgCyJzDz9vxCJD6",
  "name": "Name Surname",
  "provider": true,
  "providerName": "google",
  "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a",
  "friendshipRequests": [],
  "friends": [],
  "favorites": [],
  "createdAt": "2023-03-13T22:08:13.596Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-03-13T22:08:13.596Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

However, with Google, it looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "114524123847825110849",
  "name": "Name Surname",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNm..."
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

> Sessions are used for maintaining user specific state, including persistent objects

So each signIn action should have its corresponding data stored in the session.

Now you want to merge two sessions, you may know that it is the same user, but in fact it is like merging data for two different users, this is not logical, not even possible using next-auth.

Each time the [signIn()](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) method is called, you get a new session and you can't access old data anymore unless you store them away before you signIn with another provider, now you can merge old and new data, but you still cannot store the merged data in the session. So it's like you're not using next-auth at all and your merged data is not secure.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. When a google user signs in, I create a new user account in my db which returns a mongoDB object iD that i need in my app. I just need the mongoose ID added to the session.

Comment: what do you mean by a google user ? a user that is already signed id with the googleProvider ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: If it is already signed in what do you mean by "When a google user signs in " a user can signIn only once, the providers you make in you nextauth file are to provide multiple ways of signIn so one user can signIn with the credential provider another with the googleProvider... for example when you signIn  in stackoverflow with gmail and then you signIn with facebook.  for the system you are two different users so each one has his own session

Comment: I use several applications where I sign in using different methods but under the hood, they all retrieve the same underlining profile. I just want my users to be able to do the same.